# setting the default values if there are null in table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the below ddl of the table fdg_USER

```
CREATE TABLE fdg_user (
  id          NUMBER(32,0)  NOT NULL, 
  updateddate TIMESTAMP(6)  NULL, 
  name        VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL,
  }
```

Now when I select all the columns ain few rows I see for the column name updated by is appearing as null   I want to set the default values as name as bbb and default updateddate as 05.03.13 05:29:34

what I need to do this to add the default values for these two if they are null or if name is null then namedefault value should be insertes or if
  date is null then the date value is to be inserted

Comment: How did you get a name of `NULL` if your table clearly states `NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 1):

You use  `default defaultvalue` on each column when creating the table. See here : http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-how-to-use-default-values-with-database-columns/

It would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE fdg_user (
    id          NUMBER(32,0) NOT NULL, 
    updateddate TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP('05.03.13 05:29:34','dd.mm.yy hh24:mi:ss') NULL , 
    name        VARCHAR2(30) DEFAULT 'bbb' NOT NULL 
)
```

see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e4c2/2).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
CREATE TABLE fdg_user (
    id NUMBER(32,0) NOT NULL, 
    updateddate TIMESTAMP(6) NULL DEFAULT "05.03.13 05:29:34", 
    name VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL DEFAULT "bbb"
)
```